# Ubuntu - Plex Media Server: not seeing additional drives

Tags: mount, hard-drive, plex

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I have successfully installed Plex Media Server on my SSD which has access to my Synology NAS. I have an additional drive (NFS HDD) installed (photo below) which I would like Plex Media Server which is inside a docker (Dockstarter) to have visibility of:

[additional drives - VHDs(/dev/sdc5 is what I want to use.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPlk.png)

When I go into Plex, it seems that this drive is not visible:

[The structure doesn't include the additional drive (/dev/sdc5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpfa.png)

I have checked and the drive is mounted, but feel like I am missing something. I now know how to mount an external hard drive (nfs) but do I need to do the same thing for an internal? Could someone please advise?

System details:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Thank you for your time.

-- edit

I've now managed to mount the NFS drive manually. I changed the mount point to my home directory (/home/dandy/mnt/additionaldrive) so Plex could see it. Next up, fstab. I think it's likely to be:

'/dev/sdc5 /home/dandy/mnt/additionaldrive  nfs  nofail,defaults,rw,user 0  0' but I'm not sure?

Is there a way to also make it so it never disconnects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is a combination of mounting a drive permanently and defining it in Plex with the proper ownership/permissions.

**Mounting**

To mount a drive manually, use the following command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc5 /home/dandy/mnt/additionaldrive
```

The problem with this command, however, is that the mount won't survive a reboot. Therefore, to have it mounted during boot, you need to edit your `/etc/fstab` file. But first, you need to find the *UUID* of the particular partition that you want to mount. Use the command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` to find the *UUID*. On my system, I get the following:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul  2 16:13 0b132a87-938e-4654-b734-6a4a4105ca9c -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul  2 16:13 10442e1e-b19d-4b3a-8bb0-37c6dfb2e8ef -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul  2 16:13 2797e94e-82c5-4f66-8911-ad32fe5c8e73 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul  2 16:13 2ae71809-1068-4d24-b611-9e3d9270cc71 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul  2 16:13 fa789f63-a537-47cb-8f16-6348e4182b31 -> ../../dm-1
```

Once you identify the *UUID* for your partition, edit the `/etc/fstab` file as follows. Be sure to substitute *xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx* with the *UUID* of your partition:

```
# mount /dev/sdc5 /home/dandy/mnt/additionaldrive
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx   /home/dandy/mnt/additionaldrive  nfs defaults 0 0
```

If you notice, the options I used are simply `defaults`. This will allow *rw* access along with a couple other settings. For more information about the options and editing `/etc/fstab`, see the documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). Adjust as necessary for your situation.

If you don't want to manually type out the *UUID* while editing `/etc/fstab`, you can use the following commands to append the *UUID* to `/etc/fstab`. After that, edit `/etc/fstab` as needed.

Switch to root:

```
sudo bash
```

Make backup:

```
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

Append *UUID* to `/etc/fstab`:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep sdc | awk '{print $9}' >> /etc/fstab
```

**Plex Library Ownership/Permissions**

Next, you need to make sure that this folder and its contents have the proper ownership/permissions for Plex to be able to read and write to. Plex Media Server runs as user *plex*. Therefore the media and directories need to allow read and write access to user *plex*. This is done with the following command:

```
sudo chown -R plex:plex /home/dandy/mnt/additionaldrive
```

For more information, a good tutorial for Plex is [here](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu-linux/), and the official documentation is [here](https://support.plex.tv/articles/categories/plex-media-server/installation-and-basic-setup/).

**Side Note**

I don't recommend creating your Plex library directory within your home directory. Instead, mount it somewhere like `/mnt/addionaldrive`.

Also, you might want to consider using a group other than *plex* for your library. On my system, the directory and file ownership for my Plex Media Server library uses *plex* as the user but a different group, *boden*. This allows me more flexibility. Plex still needs to own the files, but I also want to have the directory accessible as a network drive via SMB. In order to do this, I defined a new group called *boden* that user *plex* and any other specific users are added to. Then within my Samba config file, I set it up for users to access this share point via the network. Additionally, if a file is written to the directory, it automatically defines ownership of *plex:boden*. This is handy when adding media to the library. But this is another topic you can explore on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, that helped! Have a fantastic day.